# Is it possible to chain Tableau dashboard actions to run on one click?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a tableau dashboard with two worksheets.  The second worksheet is displayed based on what is selected on a line item (row) in the first worksheet.

I would like to perform two actions.  I want the filter action to execute based on a Menu select, and I want a Change Parameter action to happen as well to control values in the second worksheet's title.

I need the two actions to run as a unit.  I have the Change Parameter working, but can't figure out how to execute the Filter action to run too.  Maybe it's not possible.

I have a related question with more details [here](https://urlisolation.com/browser?clickId=80F0704D-A1D5-47B3-8752-9E497DDB4686&traceToken=1711168007%3Bsouthernwine_hosted%3Bhttps%3A%2Fsg-links.stackoverflow.em&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F78208843%2Fhow-to-pass-a-value-from-one-tableau-worksheet-to-another-worksheets-title).

Comment: Can you provide more detail and or screenshots of what you have so far? Like is "Menu Select" a worksheet or a filter... Also your link does not seem to link to a related questions but rather the "proofpoint" website.

Comment: I have a .twbx that can help visualize what I'm after but I don't know how to attach it.